# Querying non Primary Column in Cassandra using Spark in JAVA

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I want to query my Cassandra table whose schema is

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mykeyspace.user (
    id text,
    login text,
    password text,
    firstname text,
    lastname text,
    email text,
   PRIMARY KEY(id)
   );
```

I want to query this table using login and firstname which clearly are non primary columns. I have read somewhere that Spark is very helpful in these scenarios.So I want to know that how I can query cassandra with non-primary columns using Spark.

Also I am using Java to query the database.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to use a `jdbc` connector (for example [profress makes one](https://www.progress.com/jdbc/apache-cassandra) )

Spark's [jdbc support](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#jdbc-to-other-databases) is pretty well documented

Then you can use spark dataframes to query and work with the Cassandra tables, e.g.

```
df = spark.read.jdbc('jdbc:cassandra:dbserver', 'mykeyspace.user', connectionProperties).filter('login = "foo" and firstname = "bar"')
```

(sorry my example is in python but the java api is almost identical)

Answer (score 0):

Spark is for bulk operations like scan the full table or join it with other one.
It is better to use secondary indexes or materialised view in your case:
https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlCreateIndex.html
https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlCreateMaterializedView.html

So to use index on login field:

```
CREATE INDEX ON mykeyspace.user (login);
select * from mykeyspace.user where login = 'a';
```